# How to set Caps Lock to write a character?

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout, remapping

Is it possible to change <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to a special character like <kbd>$</kbd> (most use in PHP) ?

Comment: What is the problem to use `[shift]` + `4`?

Comment: Caps lock is closer :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by `xmodmap`:

1- I find <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key value by `xev`, my CapsLock key has 66 of keycode.

2- Assign <kbd>$</kbd> on the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>:

```
$ xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = dollar"
```

[List of Keysyms Recognised by Xmodmap](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/List_of_Keysyms_Recognised_by_Xmodmap)